# Saving code - versioning in R

Tags: r

Is there any way to save your workspace code to a file? I would like to save each version of my program in R using RStudio, simply by running the code itself.

Comment: Have you looked at `?history`?

Comment: Use [git](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mick,

I suggested you use git which is available from Rstudio. Basically speaking, you firstly need to install git for your platform.

Then you need to create a directory which is already under version control. After this you simply need to create a project from Rstudio and enable version control feature. Then the remote repository will be cloned into the specified directory and Rstudio's version control features will then be available for that directory.

Details regarding how to set up version control in Rstudio can be found here: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN